Illustrator Actions Editing- Image Trace
Is there a way to edit an Image Trace action? It defaults to 'B+W' and I'm wanting to change it to 'Silhouettes' but every time I record this actions it sticks with this default preset.
Any way to work around it?
Thanks in advance!
